# mysql query for grouping datga based on certain condition

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a quiz based project where user visits and gives quiz. I want to list count of users who must have appeared and failed in each of the 5 modules Quizzes. I am getting this properly. Now if a user reappears in any of the 5 quizzes and passes in it he/she must not be included in the earlier mentioned count.

My query for counting number of users appeared and failed in all 5 modules is,

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT module_id) as module_id from tbl WHERE user_id = $userId AND cleared = 0,
```

where user_id is user's id and cleared is set to 0 if failed and 1 if passed.
Although the above query counts number of modules that a user has passed. I am using this into a function and then comparing in if statement. 
I just want to figure out what changes can I bring in here so that if a user passes in any module, they should not be included in this. I have tried but got no correct query buildup. Any suggestion will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM tbl
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT module_id) = 5 AND SUM(cleared) = 0;
--             ^^ appeared in all 5 modules        ^^ and failed them all
```

If you want to restrict the above query to just one or a few users, then you may add back the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Thanks for this. I appreciate your time and effort. But at the place of `(DISTINCT module_id) = 5` in query, I want to get this 5 by calling a function like `(DISTINCT module_id) = 'this->totalmodules()'` . Is this possible? If not then what else can be done. TIA

Comment: @Ansh I don't write much PHP, but yes, this should be possible.  You may compare the distinct count against anything, in theory.